# Spring Boot management.trace.include configuration by example

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

Spring Boot here. What are the possible values that one can specify for the `management.trace.include` property in `application.properties`, what are this property's default values, and where is all of this documented (pro tip: it's not!)?

Comment: Found [this list of valid properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) but that doesn't tell me what the possible values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twas: `org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.TraceProperties.Include`

Answer (score 3):

For Spring Boot 2.1.0 it is:

`org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.http.Include`

To see its values, see (enum constansts are processed by Spring - AUTHORIZATION_HEADER becomes authorization-header):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/trace/http/Include.html#enum.constant.summary

Default value can be found here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html